# want to figure out why struct elements changed while i didn't do anything

Tags: c, queue

Its a SqQueue,when i try to get the elements in queue,i found queue struct members has changed but i dont know why.when i first use function myCircularQueueRear,struct elements which obj points to has changed.In the function, i didnt change those datas.(leetcode 266)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define OK 1
#define ERROR 0
#define INFEASIBLE -1
#define OVERFLOW -2
#define MAXQSIZE 100
typedef int Status;
typedef int QElemType;
typedef struct{
    QElemType *base;
    int front;
    int rear;
    int size;
    int tag;
}MyCircularQueue,*SqQueue;

/** Initialize your data structure here. Set the size of the queue to be k. */

SqQueue myCircularQueueCreate(int k) {
    MyCircularQueue Queue;
    SqQueue Q=&Queue;
    Q->size=k;
    Q->tag=0;
    Q->base=(QElemType *)malloc(k*sizeof(QElemType));
    if(!Q->base)exit(OVERFLOW);
    Q->front=Q->rear=0;
    return Q;
}

/** Insert an element into the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful. */
bool myCircularQueueEnQueue(SqQueue obj, int value) {
    if(obj->tag==1)return false;
    obj->base[obj->rear]=value;
    obj->rear=(obj->rear+1)%obj->size;
    if(obj->front==obj->rear)obj->tag=1;
    return true;
}

/** Delete an element from the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful. */
bool myCircularQueueDeQueue(SqQueue obj) {
    if(obj->front==obj->rear&&obj->tag==0)return false;
    obj->front=(obj->front+1)%obj->size;
    if(obj->tag==1)obj->tag=0;
    return true;
}

/** Get the front item from the queue. */
int myCircularQueueFront(SqQueue Q) {
    if(Q->front==Q->rear&&Q->tag==0)return ERROR;
    return Q->base[Q->front];
}

/** Get the last item from the queue. */
int myCircularQueueRear(SqQueue Q) {
    if(Q->front==Q->rear&&Q->tag==0)return ERROR;
    return Q->base[(Q->rear+Q->size-1)%Q->size];
}

/** Checks whether the circular queue is empty or not. */
bool myCircularQueueIsEmpty(SqQueue Q) {
    if(Q->front==Q->rear&&Q->tag==0)return true;
    else return false;
}

/** Checks whether the circular queue is full or not. */
bool myCircularQueueIsFull(SqQueue Q) {
    if(Q->tag==1)return true;
    else return false;
}

void myCircularQueueFree(MyCircularQueue* Q) {
    free(Q->base);
}

int main(){
    SqQueue obj = myCircularQueueCreate(3);
    myCircularQueueEnQueue(obj, 1);
    myCircularQueueEnQueue(obj, 2);
    myCircularQueueEnQueue(obj, 3);
    myCircularQueueEnQueue(obj, 4);
```

when i run the following line,the struct elemtents obj points to changed.

```
    printf("%d ",myCircularQueueRear(obj));
    printf("%d ",myCircularQueueIsFull(obj));

    myCircularQueueDeQueue(obj);
    myCircularQueueEnQueue(obj, 4);
    printf("%d ",myCircularQueueRear(obj));
    /*int param_3 = myCircularQueueFront(obj);

    int param_4 = myCircularQueueRear(obj);

    bool param_5 = myCircularQueueIsEmpty(obj);

    bool param_6 = myCircularQueueIsFull(obj);

    myCircularQueueFree(obj);*/
    return 0;
}
```

IDE recomend stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You should construct an [mre]. There are several functions you don't even use, so why show them to us? Also, you're obviously using modern C, which includes `bool`, `true` and `false`. So why use `#define FALSE 0` and such? Also, you say that something changed? How do you know? What output do you get and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
SqQueue myCircularQueueCreate(int k) {
    MyCircularQueue Queue;
    SqQueue Q=&Queue;
    ...
    ...
    return Q;
}
```

you return the address of a local variable. That variable stop to exist when the function returns. So using the pointer afterwards accesses an object that no longer exists in the system.

Use dynamic allocation instead of a local variable, i.e.

```
SqQueue Q =malloc(sizeof *Q);
```

BTW: `typedef` of pointers are often considered a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have an UB here:

```
SqQueue myCircularQueueCreate(int k) {
    MyCircularQueue Queue;  // stack allocation
    SqQueue Q=&Queue;
    Q->size=k;
    /* ... */
    return Q;  // returning the address of a stack object
}
```

Once you finished that function, the allocated structure is deallocated